# Which of the common sorting algorithms can be parallelized?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, parallel-computing

I want to know that whether which of the following algorithm can be parallelized?

Bubble Sort,
Insertion Sort,
Selection Sort,
Shell Sort,
Quick Sort,
Merge Sort,
Radix Sort.

Those which can't be, please explain me briefly that how? Or please try to tell me in simple words that what is parallelism in sorting algorithms.

Comment: An algorithm can be parallelized if some of its steps can be done in parallel (possibly with minor modifications to the algorithm). If you work through the high-level steps of each algorithm, you should figure out where you can do this.

Comment: What have you tried? i.e what is your own thought about different algorithms, e.g radix sort can be parallelized or not? Why? Is not important if your answers are wrong, but we should see that you already tried to solve them yourself.

Comment: The answers are supposed to be useful for others. We do not care if the OP has tried or not.

Comment: @Val I am care with many other members. We expect at least very few thoughs from OP. See meta discussion: http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-should-we-do-with-questions-without-effort

Comment: Why do you expect thoughts of this gentlemen more than others?

Comment: @Val, Who is this other? By the way you can post your opinion as an answer to the meta post, I don't know this gentelman, and please don't treat with such a comments as personal attack.

Comment: @Val You may not be aware of this, but on [cs.SE] it *is* customary to ask for display of effort. Case in point, this question asks essentially on a book worth of answers but does not show that even the most fundamental Google query has been made.

Comment: Since the question is impossibly broad, I'm closing. Please restrict yourself to a single algorithm at a time and do some research before you ask, and include your findings. (I know for a fact that for some of these algorithms, you *will* find something.)

Comment: @Raphael Do you want the single yes/no answer? Why do you call the 7 yes/no string `impossibly broad`? It names you 7 algorithms and each has yes/no answer. Where is the infinity?

Comment: @Val: 1) Yes-no answers are bad, and so are questions asking for such. So I was assuming that a good answer to this question would contain elaborate (dis)proofs for every algorithm. 2) I never said "infinitely", but "impossibly" (as in, impossible to deal with on this platform).

Comment: "WHere" does not imply the proof. It implies a short review. You tell how difficult it is to paralellize an algorithm. You give people the clue in which direction to see. Proves can be found in references.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/nesl/algorithms.html#sort).
Parallelism can be achieved by using  pipeline of processing units or using multiple processor [link](http://courses.teresco.org/cs338_s06/tutorials/sorting/).

For comparison based sorting lets take an example of quick sort , in quick sort after we find the pivot then we can process two parts in parallel.

```
quicksort(A)
if |A| = 1 then return A
i := rand int(|A|)
p := A[i]
in parallel do 
 L := quicksort({a : a ∈ A | a < p})
 E := {a : a ∈ A | a = p}
 G := quicksort({a : a ∈ A | a > p})
return L ++ E ++ G
```

Another example we can take is of Radix sort which does not directly compare keys to determine ordering.The basic radix sort algorithm (whether serial or parallel) examines the keys to be sorted one “digit” position at a time, starting with the least significant digit in each key.For implementation in parallel see this tutorial [Parallel In-Place Radix Sort](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/parallel-in-place-radix-sort-simplified/229000734)